# secure communication between paypal client and server

Tags: paypal

We have successfully created a paypal (non -website)  client  and tested it against the sandbox. I see that the communication between the server is encrypted.

1. Do we not need a client side ssl certificate for secure
   communication with an ssl server?

I have looked into the stubs generated for SOAP clients and the rest sdk, and I cannot see  how the communication is encrypted.
Any information to throw light on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. Otherwise, how else would you communicate with an SSL server if both sides have to have keys?

When you make an API call, you make it to their HTTPS site. This encrypts the traffic between you and them. There's an excellent [answer about this on Security Stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) which discusses the nuts and bolts of SSL/TLS if you need more detail.